# How can I search for addresses close to my user's current location using Mapbox's Geocoder API?

Tags: mapbox, geocoding, mapbox-gl-js

I am using the Mapbox Geocoder API to search for addresses:

`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${this.searchKeyword}.json?country=us&access_token=${this.accessToken}`

It's working great, but I would like for it to search for addresses close to my user's current location (I have the lat long). Right now it's giving me results on the opposite side of the country.

So something like

`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${this.searchKeyword}.json?country=us&access_token=${this.accessToken}&near=123.456, 121.654`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Mapbox Geocoding API documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#request-format), it describes the `proximity` parameter as

> Bias local results based on a provided location. Options are longitude,latitude coordinates.

So in JavaScript you can form the URL as:

`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${query}.json?country=${country}&access_token=${accessToken}&proximity=${nearLongitude},${nearLatitude}`

If you're doing this in JavaScript you can use the [Mapbox JS SDK](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js), see the [Geocoding service](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js/blob/master/docs/services.md#forwardgeocode).

If you're doing this on the web and using the [Mapbox Geocoder control](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder), there is a [`proximity` option](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/master/API.md#mapboxgeocoder) and a `trackProximity` option to set the proximity automatically based on the current map view.